# Shannon Diversity Program: basic questions

Tags: python, indexing, calculation

I am a biology student trying to get into programming and have some issue with a basic index calculator I am trying to write for a research project. I need a program that will prompt the user to input data points one at a time, perform the proper calculation (`-1*(x*ln(x))`) on each data point, and enter that new calculated value into an array. Once the user inputs `'done'`, I would like the program to sum the array values and return that index value.

This is what I have. I am very new so apologies for any blaring mistakes. Any points in the right direction are very appreciated.

```
import math

print('This program calculates a Shannon Diversity '
      'Index value for a set of data points entered by the user.'
      ' when prompted enter a species number value,then press enter. '
      'COntinue until all data points have been entered. '
      'Upon completion, enter the word done.')

def Shannonindex():

    index = []
    entries = 1,000,000
    endKey = 'done'

    for i in range(entries):
        index = [input("Enter a value: ")]

        if index != endKey:
        entry = p
        p = -1*(x*ln(x))
        index.append(p)
        else Sindex = sum(index)

        return Sindex

print('Your Shannon Diversity Value is: ", Sindex)
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a huge number of problms here.

- You need to get your variables straight.

  - You're trying to use `index` to mean both the list of values, and the input string. It can't mean both things at once.
  - You're trying to use `x` without defining it anywhere. Presumably it's supposed to be the float value of the input string? If so, you have to say that.
  - You're trying to use `p` to define `entry` before `p` even exists. But it's not clear what `entry` is even useful for, since you never use it.
- You also need to get your control flow straight.

  - What code is supposed to run in that `else` case? Either it has to include the `return`, or you need some other way to break out of the loop.
- You also need to get your types straight. `[input(…)]` is going to give you a list with one element, the input string. It's hard to imagine what that would be useful for. You can't compare that list to `'done'`, or convert it to a float. What you want is just the input string itself.
- You can't just guess at what functions might exist. There's no function named `ln`. Look at the docs for [Built-in Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html), the [`math`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html) module, and anything else that looks like it might be relevant to find the function you need.
- `1,000,000` is not a number, but a tuple of three numbers.

  - You can write `1_000_000`, or just `1000000`.
  - But it's not clear why you need a limit in the first place. Why not just loop forever until the enter `done`?
- You've defined a function, but you never call it, so it doesn't do any good.

So, let's sort out these problems:

```
import math

def Shannonindex():    
    index = []
    endKey = 'done'    
    while True:
        value = input("Enter a value: ")
        if value != endKey:
            x = float(value)
            p = -1 * (x * math.log(x))
            index.append(p)
        else:
            Sindex = sum(index)
            return Sindex

Sindex = Shannonindex()
print('Your Shannon Diversity Value is: ", Sindex)
```

---

There are still many ways you could improve this:

- Add some error handling, so if the user typos `13.2.4` or `1O`, it tells them to try again instead of bailing out on the whole thing.
- You don't actually need to build a list, just keep a running total.
- If you reverse the sense of the `if`/`else` it will probably be more readable.
- You're not actually calculating the Shannon diversity index. That's not the sum of `-x ln x`, it's the sum of `-p ln p` where each `p` is the *proportion* of `x / sum(all x)`. To handle that, you need to keep all the raw `x` values in a list, so you can convert that to a list of `p` values, so you can sum those.

Comment: Beat me to it, and with a much more comprehensive answer, too! Nice one

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the help. Its all a bit overwhelming. I can see several things I did wrong up front, some of the rest are a bit hard to wrap my brain around. I can see where I was messing up the actual calculation.
I toyed with it some more and it runs, but I know it is incorrect, and I know I am not having it use the values I want when I want them. I tried to comment out my thought process, Ill update the question

Answer (score 0):

```
import math
index = []

for i in range(1,100000):
    val = input("Enter a value: ")

    if val =='done':
        break
    else:
        x = int(val)
        p = -1*(x*math.log(x))
        index.append(p)

print ("The value of index is %s:"%index)
```

=================================================

This is the simplified form of your code, since you are new to python. 
This might help you get the values stored in a list and calculate it until you type done.